# Multi-language lambda functions within the same directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, package, terraform

I have few lambda written in Typescript and few other in Java.Should I place both the packages in a single directory or maintain a different directory based on the language.We use terraform for deploying Infra and Jenkins for CI/CD. Im also thinking about common code sharing between the lambda functions ,not sure how does that work if we keep all the lambda in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest few things here

1. Group your code in different repositories which will help you with better code management, less code size on lambda as lambda has limit on how much you can upload.
2. It is better to group different languages in different repo as they are different runtime and hence the settings will be different.
3. Also, if you make change to typescript code, there shouldn't be any need to touch the java functions and vice versa.
4. If you have some common code, I would suggest you to look for AWS Lambda layers (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). This gives you capability to share the code/bin/executable etc across multiple functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mark B could you please provide elaborate when you say 'Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving'.I am seeing most of my questions being closed for the same reason.